# Why isn't Odoo picking up my module?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

I’ve added a module directory to /home/deploy/host-addons. Starting up Odoo definitely knows about it:

> 2014-09-08 10:50:08,533 5198 INFO ? openerp: addons
>   paths:['/home/deploy/odoo/local/data/addons/8.0',
>   u'/home/deploy/odoo/build/8.0/openerp/addons',
>   u'/home/deploy/odoo/build/8.0/addons', u'/home/deploy/host-addons']

There's nothing strange in the addons folder:

```
$ ls -dl /home/deploy/host-addons/**/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  24 Sep  8 03:30 /home/deploy/host-addons/test/__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 275 Sep  8 03:31 /home/deploy/host-addons/test/__openerp__.py
```

The contents are from the example at: http://odoo-80.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howtos/website.html

**/home/deploy/host-addons/test/__init__.py**

```
__author__ = 'kitsunde'
```

**/home/deploy/host-addons/test/__openerp__.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    # The human-readable name of your module, displayed in the interface
    'name': "Academy",
    # A more extensive description
    'description': """
    """,
    # Which modules must be installed for this one to work
    'depends': ['base'],
}
```

Why isn't Odoo picking up the addon?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Restarting the server or just clicking on update doesn't update the list of installable modules. You have to go to Settings -> Users -> Enable Technical Features. Then there will be a new option that says "Update Modules List" in the Module category to the left on the settings page.

[image]

Comment: saved my day! But how to force updating on startup (running `python odoo.py --addons-path=addons,../myaddons`)?

Comment: This did not work for me,  even if I remove older modules they still would appear in the list, but if I remove the entry from ir_module_module table they get removed, but it still won't show my custom module.

Comment: I have installed the odoo 9 but i have not seen the option Settings -> Users -> Enable Technical Features ? Is it different in odoo  9 ?

Comment: Odoo 11 does not have this option. outdated answer

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem by Odoo v9, i try @Kit-Sunde method but i cant see The **Technical Features** checkbox but i found a way to show all menus in [this link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/8391), Try Odoo url with debug parameter, similar below:

> 127.0.0.1:8069/web?**debug**

In this mood you can see all menus, and then goto `settings > apps` and then click on **Update Apps List** from left sidebar, now you can search your module and isntall :)